# WCF service soapUI issue

Tags: wcf, soapui, wshttpbinding

I have a WCF web service created, the service uses wshttbinding and is working fine when i try invoking by adding service reference (with certificates supplied).When i try invoking it from soapUI i am getting an error. I tried disabling the security mode but found out that the following line of code is causing the issue.

```
string certInfo = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

I am getting the above value as null. Is there any way i can pass this context from within soapUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In soapUI, you need to specify the `Outgoing WSS`, which specifies which project-level outgoing WS-Security configuration to apply to outgoing requests.

The following links should provide sufficient background information:
http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html
http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html